# Loading a local file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onload

Searching and reading here got me part way to my solution, which is a workaround for loading a text file using oft recommended code such as:

```
function FileRead(U) 
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        X=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
        X=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

  X.open('GET', U, false );
  X.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
  X.send();
    return X.responseText;
}
```

This works well for me, so far, on PCs, but not on Macs.

So I used a technique recommended here where I designate the local file as a source in a script, and that worked well for several pages. For the other pages I need to define the source at runtime, taking the path from local storage. Again, tips here helped, but I hit a snag. The following code, located in the header, gets thing rolling.

```
<script>
    var albumPath = '';
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") 
    {
        albumPath = localStorage.getItem('photo_album_path');
    }
    if (albumPath.substr(albumPath-1,1) !== '/') {albumPath = albumPath +'/'}

    var Raw_Album_Info = '';
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = albumPath+"album_info.txt";
    document.head.appendChild(script);
</script> 

<script src="../scripts/common.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../scripts/photos_pages.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>alert(Raw_Album_Info);</script>
```

The code above does not work unless I include the final "alert" line. It displays a blank message, but it works. If I add a second alert statement it shows the contents of the source file.

At the bottom of the page I have this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
window.onload = LoadAlbumInfo();
var slideIndex = 2;
showSlides();
</script>
```

LoadAlbumInfo parses the file and draws content on the page.

Clearly there is an onload-type issue going on here but I can't figure it out. Any suggestions?

Bump on Feb 11. Still looking for a solution.

I tried everything I can think of, from setTimer to moving the code around, to a second window.onLoad statement, and the only thing that gets this to work is inserting an alert statement in the code anywhere between where the script is created and when the script element is used.

If I can't figure this one out I can always resort to putting 8-10 identical html files in different folders, but that would be a pain to maintain, and not pretty.

As for using php etc, this project is going on a thumb drive. It is stand-alone. No server, no Internet.

Comment: Whatever site or resource you're looking at for help is showing you very old code. Any browser released in the last 8 years has native support for `XMLHttpRequest()`, so there is no need for the `if/else` statement you've created - - just make an instance of the object. Also, `language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"` hasn't been needed on `script` tags for many years as well. You can remove that part.

Comment: `IE5, IE6` <- you sure you want to handle these? likely not; remove!

Comment: I'm a bit confused why you're loading a text file into a `script` element. Why not just use ajax (`XMLHttpRequest`) to get the contents? Also, loading any file from the server is asynchronous, so it may not be loaded by the time your function is called. Better to add an [`onreadystatechange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange) event handler to `XMLHttpRequest`, check the state and run your function when it is completely loaded.

Comment: The code that you say works well for you is incorrect and likely isn't working correctly at all. You haven't set up a "success" callback for your XHR component and are attempting to get the `.responseText` immediately after sending the request, which would never really work. You need to place that in the success callback. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress) for how to use an XHR.

Comment: This first snippet has worked for me for years, but I'd never tried it on a Mac until now. That snippet does make an XMLHttpRequest but a Mac this was tested on last night objected to it. Many other posts on this site confirmed it could be a problem, that local file access is generally blocked. A solution suggested was to make it a script element, which works for fixed file names but is not ideal because I'll have to edit all of my txt files. It works for variable file names, too, but not correctly, not without the "alert" statement.

Comment: I should add that all files are local and none are on a server.

Comment: *I should add that all files are local and none are on a server.* <-- That's the problem. AJAX only works over HTTP/HTTPS. And, as I've said, the code that "works" is only working because the file is being retrieved quick enough, but that isn't a guarantee. You are not using the XHR correctly and should read the link I shared and correctly set it up. The way you have it, it could fail at any point, for example if the file simply gets any bigger. You can simply set up a local server to fetch your file from and then it will work correctly everywhere.

Comment: The ajax code is out at this point, but I'll look into the events in your link. As as for the <script language...> bits, I am removing those to tidy things up, but old code or not, examples using it are everywhere.

Comment: My problem at this point is the script created when the page loads that retrieves the information I need to populate the page. Yes, I could use php or something else, but this project will be deployed on a thumb drive and will not interact with any servers. It is totally stand-alone. I can get it to work in Firefox only if I place an "alert" statements in there somewhere after the script has been created. I've tired setTimer and a few other things but nothing else has worked.

Comment: If I can't figure this one out I can always resort to putting 8-10 identical html files in different folders, but that would be a pain to maintain, and not pretty.