# how to pass a parameter in the script tag in the head

Tags: javascript, html

I have a html page `index.html`. In the `head tag` of that page I want to define a script src:

```
<script src="http://www.example/hrm.js?pId=5"></script>
```

I want the pId number to be filled in by the parameter I give to my html file. 
for example if I open `.../index.html?pId=6`, I want in the script tag of that page

```
<script src="http://www.example/hrm.js?pId=6"></script>
```

How can I do that?
I tried this: [Use JS variable to set the src attribute for <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150409/use-js-variable-to-set-the-src-attribute-for-script-tag)
but the problem is that I have multiple script to load ! and nothting work anymore when I put that piece of code.

Comment: you could use JavaScript to read the parameter from the querystring (hint: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), and then write script which itself creates the new script tag, and concatenate the parameter value into the src string. Hint: https://cleverbeagle.com/blog/articles/tutorial-how-to-load-third-party-scripts-dynamically-in-javascript . Did you do any research into this yourself? Or make any attempt at all? We mostly like to help people fix their code, not do all their research and coding for them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JS variable to set the src attribute for <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150409/use-js-variable-to-set-the-src-attribute-for-script-tag)
use javascript to get the current url parameter and then execute something like `document.write("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.example/hrm.js?p"+ x + "'><\/scr" + "ipt>");`on page load.

Another option is to use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) if you have jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use JS variable to set the src attribute for <script> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11150409/use-js-variable-to-set-the-src-attribute-for-script-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var pId = new URL(document.currentScript.getAttribute('src')).searchParams.get("pId");
```

references:

- [How may I reference the script tag that loaded the currently-executing script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/403967/387194)
- [MDN docs about URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Note: according to MDN URL is not supported by IE, see the link to see the browsers that support it, probably there is polyfill. [currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is also not supported by IE.